# Throw multiple-template class in a template template parameter - template binding?

Tags: c++, templates, template-templates

Given the following class:

```
template <class T, template <typename> class B>
class A { B<T> b; };
```

I can now write code like such:

```
A<float, MyVector> a1;
A<int, MySet> a2;
```

What is the most elegant way to put multi-parameter classes of which all parameters are specified except one, in B? Like a map with int-keys? The only thing I can come up with is this:

```
template <class U> using C = MyMap<int, U>;
A<float, C<int>> a3;
```

Is there such a template equivalent to std::bind, where we can provide only a part of the parameters and leave one of them open? I'm quite sure the language doesn't provide for this, but people must've solved this before.

```
A<float, MyMap<int, _>> a3;
```

Comment: Note that `std::vector<T, Allocator>` is not directly compatible with `template <typename> class B`.

Comment: Ah yes, my bad; I'll update the post to reflect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a built-in template equivalent to `std::bind`, but you can write one yourself. Here's a simple version which binds the first template argument which you could extend to suit your needs:

```
template <typename T, template <typename...> class B>
struct bind_t1 {
    template <typename... Ts>
    using type = B<T,Ts...>;   
};
```

Then you just use `bind_t1` like so:

```
A<float, bind_t1<int, std::map>::type> a3;
```

Note that for your example, you'll need to modify your template parameters to take a variadic template template:

```
template <class T, template <typename...> class B>
class A { B<T> b; };
```

---

Here's a slightly extended version which can bind a number of contiguous elements at the start of the parameter list:

```
template <template <typename...> class B, typename... Ts>
struct bind_nt1 {
    template <typename... Us>
    using type = B<Ts...,Us...>;   
};

//Usage
A<std::less<int>, bind_nt1<std::map, int, float>::type> a3;
```

---

Here's a generic version based on the way `std::bind` does things. It doesn't do any validation and probably has some edge cases, but it's a good starting point. Thanks to [Piotr Skotnicki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3953764/piotr-skotnicki) for improvements.

```
template <std::size_t N> 
struct placeholder{};

template <template <typename...> class B, typename... Ts>
struct bind_t {
private:
    template <typename T, typename UTuple>
    struct resolve_placeholder {
        using type = T;
    };

    template <std::size_t N, typename UTuple>
    struct resolve_placeholder<placeholder<N>, UTuple> {
        using type = typename std::tuple_element<N-1, UTuple>::type;
    };

public:
    template <typename... Us>
    using type = B<typename resolve_placeholder<Ts, std::tuple<Us...>>::type...>;
};


//Usage 
A<int, bind_t<std::map, float, placeholder<1>, std::less<float>>::type> a3;
```

Using this, you can even change the order of template parameters:

```
//std::map<int,float>
bind_t<std::map, placeholder<2>, placeholder<1>>::type<float, int> b;
```

Comment: Expanding a parameter pack of `Ts` by means of a tuple and an index sequence looks redundant

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Thanks, fixed.

Comment: I meant [an even simpler solution](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f136627cea86bbc7)

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Yeah, that's nicer. Do you want to post an answer with it or do you mind if I just edit it in?

Comment: @TartanLlama no no, I won't mind, it's still your solution