# Why can't you template a template?

Tags: c++, templates

In C++ there are 2 template types (to my knowledge): template classes and template functions. Why is it not possible to have a template of template? (be it class, or function, or other template). Has it ever been considered in standards? Does it break C++ syntax/spirit in a way?
I know it may sound crazy, and it's easy to get around.

What is possible with C++:

```
template<bool b>
class TemplateDependingOnBool
{
public:
  template<typename T>
  class TheTemplateWeWant{};
}
```

What would be great:

```
template<bool b>
template<typename T>
class TheTemplateWeWant{};
```

and call it in a policy-based style (that's where it's really interesting):

```
template<typename T, template<typename> class ThePolicy = TheTemplateWeWant<true> >
class Foo {};
```

The way it's possible to do now is to use:

```
template<typename T,
  template<typename> class ThePolicy = TemplateDependingOnBool<true>::TheTemplateWeWant >
class Foo{};
```

which is not very elegant.

**EDIT:**
I know I can template on 2 parameters. The goal is to use the underlying template class (the templated template) as something by itself, be it in a template alias or a template template parameter (as shown in my example).
Policy-based design is a reference to Andrei Alexandrescu's [Modern C++ Design](http://www.amazon.fr/Modern-Design-Generic-Programming-Patterns/dp/0201704315), which is the main reason why the feature I'm asking might be useful (because templates are used as template parameters).

Comment: You are supposed to write `template<bool b, typename T> class TheTemplateWeWant{};`

Comment: When you mention "policy-based style" it makes me think of the [concepts proposal](https://isocpp.org/blog/2013/02/concepts-lite-constraining-templates-with-predicates-andrew-sutton-bjarne-s).

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking here exactly.

Comment: I really don't see the advantage over multiple template parameters.

Comment: Can you give a concrete use case that you want to solve with that? I am currently not seeing why this is strictly needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With C++11, you're wrong in assuming only two types of templates. There are also [type aliases](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) which allow

```
template <bool b, typename T>
class TheTemplateWeWant { ... };

template<typename T>
using ThePolicy = TheTemplateWeWant<true, T>
```

Comment: Thanks, probably the closest answer to what I'm looking for. It still requires another declaration (my question was about the language, and about IF, and if not WHY several levels of templating depth could be imagined and implemented).

Comment: @maxbc: Raymond Chen said about Windows features (but the same applies to C++ features): "All proposals start at -100; there has to be a _very_ good reason to add something". That answers your question "why not?" : because the language is already complex enough as it is. Note that C++ got this third type of template because it's a fairly simple mechanism that obsoleted many complex constructs (see my other C++98 answer, boost.MPL).

Comment: That's probably the biggest part of the answer I was looking for. My reasons certainly don't score a +100 to introduce something so complex in the language.

Answer (score 4):

If I'm understanding what you're asking correctly (and I'm not entirely clear on your question), then you could write your template taking two parameters:

```
template <bool b, typename T>
class TheTemplateWeWant { ... };
```

add a metafunction to partially apply the `bool`:

```
template <bool b>
struct PartiallyWant {
    template <typename T>
    using type = TheTemplateWeWant<b, T>;
};
```

and then pass that as your policy:

```
template<typename T,
         template<typename> class ThePolicy = PartiallyWant<true>::type >
class Foo { ... };

Foo<char, PartiallyWant<false>::type> foo;
```

---

So why not just layer the templates like you propose? The simple answer is that there's no reason to. If `TheTemplateWeWant` has two template parameters (`bool b` and `typename T`, regardless of whether it's an "inner" class or not), then we should express it as such. And if we want to only apply one type or the other, that's something that has fewer use-cases than a general template while also being solvable with just a few lines of boilerplate. Additionally, what if we had such a feature, and now I want to partially apply the `T` instead of the `b`? With a few lines of boilerplate I can again accomplish the same thing, but with the layering this would be impossible.

Comment: I don't think you should wrap it, you can simple using the template.

Comment: @Melkon How would you use the template? It takes two template parameters and we need to pass it to something that takes one template parameter.

Comment: Hmm, you are right, this abstraction is probably required. :(

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know you cand you simply that, and it works just as you want - class templated with 2 parameters.

```
template<bool b, typename T>
class TheTemplateWeWant{}; //valid in C++
```

Comment: The OP probably dreams of curryfication on templates, or partial evaluation. He should look into Common Lisp (whose metaprogramming abilities are much better than in C++11)

Comment: Even though it ends with a question mark, it's probably not really a question to the OP. It's more of an answer phrased as a rhetorical question.

Comment: @erip it was rather answer, but i'm not SURE 100% if that was what he wanted. Thats why i asked at the end and if he'd reply no, then i'd change it/remove it.

Comment: The OP provided a use case.  This answer does not solve the OP's use case.  Can you demonstrate how your syntax can be used to bind one parameter to your template, and leave the other one unbound?

Comment: Bonus points if you can do it generically without having to wrap non-type parameters.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32395970/496161)'s an example of binding template arguments, but it doesn't work for non-type parameters (but you could wrap them in `std::integral_constant`).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch it's not curryfication of template, nor partial specialization. It's just several levels of template: a class template is a class that depends on a template. Why not do the same with a template? A template class that depends on a template. The question is more about the language (see question marks in the post, and the title) than finding concrete solutions to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

What you're  describing is partial binding of *template* parameters, just like `std::bind` can turn a binary function into a unary function.

For metaprogramming madness, there's Boost.MPL. They do have a template `boost::mpl::bind`.